# Play Framework route not working though defined correctly

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have this simple route defined in Play's routes:

```
POST /test/post/$id<[0-9]+>  controllers.Test.post(id: Long)
```

This is the code of `Test.post` method:

```
public static Result post(long id)
{
    return ok("working");
}
```

Another route in the same controller, `POST /test controllers.Test.index()` is working fine. However whenever I visit `http://localhost:9000/test/post/3`, I get a 'Connection reset' error in firefox immediately, and in google chrome I get a 'empty response' error. All other routes are working correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to rule out the highly unlikely case that you missed the obvious: by "whenever I visit `http://localhost:9000/test/post/3`", you mean via a `POST` request, and not by typing the address in your browser? (Because your route looks good... and anyway, if you did access it via `GET`, you should get an error message that the route could not be found...)

Comment: Just a tiny test: use a `Long` instead of a `long`in your action.

Comment: @nico_ekito Great catch, that was it. Post an answer if you'd like and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Long` object instead of the `long` native type in your Action :

```
public static Result post(Long id)
{
    return ok("working");
}
```